# How can I reorder a range plot by a max y value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

In fact there are two issues. My original issue is the question stated in the title. The data frame contains minimum and maximum y values, and I would like to reorder Letters, located on the flipped X axis, in descending order by the y value, Max.

The second issue has come up while trying to reproduce the issue. I'm not sure how come Min is plotted over several values multiple times on each Letter, whereas Max is only plotted once per x value (as intended). This didn't happen in the original code.

I've tried writing reorder() into aes(), **ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Letter,-Max)))**, but there was no effect.

```
Letters <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"))
Max <- sample(20:12,8)
Min <- sample(11:5,8)

df <- data.frame(Letters, Max, Min)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Letters)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Min, ymax = Max, x = Letters),
                 size = 1.5, alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Max), colour = "tomato3") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Min), colour = "aquamarine4") +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("Score Ranges") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `fct_reorder` from the forcats package (part of tidyverse).

```r
library(tidyverse)

Letters <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"))
Max <- sample(20:12, 8, replace=TRUE)
Min <- sample(11:5, 8, replace=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(Letters, Max, Min)

df |> 
  mutate(
    Letters = fct_reorder(Letters, Max, .fun = max)
  ) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Letters)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Min, ymax = Max, x = Letters),
                 linewidth = 1.5, alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Max), colour = "tomato3") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Min), colour = "aquamarine4") +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("Score Ranges") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for! Will also add that my original variable names (min and max, written in all lowercase) apparently were causing errors.